# Keyboard Down in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some textfield in which when i click it shows me keyboard , but when i click anywhere on the page the keyboard do not disappears . This is my code for resign of first responder. Whats wrong in my code.

[image]

Comment: can you try adding [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: Add code not upload screenshot of code @umer

Comment: Just use tap gesture...its easy to use..@umer

Comment: where to add it? @iAnurag

Comment: Just Use `[self.view endEditing:YES];` ,

Comment: do you have , any otherSubview over Your view .....may be u are using ScrollView  ? am i right

Comment: you could try https://stackoverflow.com/a/45013076/4061501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReceived:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)tapReceived:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.@iAnurag

Comment: Welcome...glad to help:)

Comment: Im facing one problem after following ur code.@iAnurag

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: i have a drop down on a button . When i apply ur code it works fine but when i click button and select the items from list the r not selected from there. When i remove ur code they work fine. @iAnurag

Comment: Hi Umer just implement this delegate method  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures when required.
    if ((touch.view == yourButton)) {//change it to your condition
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

Comment: can u explain this in answer? @luckyShubhra

Comment: I edited ans. Disallow recognition of tap gestures when you select the items from list. If list if tableView remove yourButton with table view.

Answer (score 1):

Create iVar for `UIGestureRecognizer`

```
UIGestureRecognizer *tapper;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    tapper.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
}
```

Dismiss what ever is currently editing:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
        if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
            [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
```

Or

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
        if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
          [self.view endEditing:YES];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one `UITapGestureRecognizer` as a class variable.

```
@interface ViewController() {
    UITapGestureRecognizer  *tapGesture;
}    

- (void)viewDidLoad  {
   [super viewDidLoad]
   tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
}
```

Add gesture on `textfield` delegates `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, And remove it on `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
}
```

Implement tap gesture selection

```
- (void)dismissKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Down vote without comment will not help. Please add description

Comment: It may be to do with the Objective-C vs Swift, the answer was expected to be in Objective-C, note @Subramanian I did not do the downvote though... Just saw that it may be to do with the Language...

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice, Thanks for info. I will update too..  @Burnie777

Comment: @Burnie777 Thanks. I have update the answer with Objective - C

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; 
 }
 -(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [yourtextfield resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: please look at [answer]. Code-only answers aren't useful for the community

Answer (score 0):

Add Tap Gesture on your Top View 
 you you havn't  any subview which may hide your Root view
than only use self.view
 if you are using ScrollView than add TapGesture on your ScrollView

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDissmiss:)];
         [self.view addGestureRecognizer: tap];
    }
```

Handle Tap Gesture

```
  -(void)tapDissmiss:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
    {
       [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
```